# Excel, adding more information to a cell in a structured way

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have an excel-sheet with a plan for a year. Using weeks for columns and then a color indicator for weeks where "stuff" happens.

Like this:

[image]

My question is: Is there a way (built in or using add ons) to add information to this cell in a more structred way?

I'm thinking maybe a little form with

- Name
- Description
- Budget
- Yada yada
- Foo

This way I would be able to keep my overview but at the same time add some more information to each cell.

Anyone that know about a way to achieve this?

Comment: Are you looking to have users enter this information into cells on a separate sheet or will do you want them to enter the information directly into the cells pictured?

Comment: @PFitz I want the info to be stored/connected to this cell - I've looked at a vba UserForm and then from there store the values somewhere. But I wanted to see if there a solution already out there.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a User Form with some textboxes and a button for saving the values in the same col/row in another sheet called "Data".

Something like this:

```
Dim xml As String

xml = xml + "<CellDetails>"
xml = xml + "  <Budget>" + UserForm1.txtBudget.Text + "</Budget>"
xml = xml + "  <Comments>" + UserForm1.txtComments.Text + "</Comments>"
xml = xml + "  <StartDate>" + Format(MonthView1.Value, "yyyy-mm-dd") + "</StartDate>"
xml = xml + "  <EndDate>" + Format(MonthView2.Value, "yyyy-mm-dd") + "</EndDate>"
xml = xml + "</CellDetails>"

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range(Selection.Address).Value = xml
```

Then I trigger this from the Sheet using a event-listner on the "right click" of a cell and populate the form controls with the values.

Private Sub Workbook_SheetBeforeRightClick(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

On Error Resume Next

' Only trigger this if the Ctrl-key is pressed
  If IsControlKeyDown() = True Then

```
    If Not ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range(Selection.Address).Value = "" Then

        Dim XDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument
        Set XDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
        XDoc.LoadXML (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range(Selection.Address).Value)

        ' Setting the form values
        UserForm1.txtBudget.Text = XDoc.SelectSingleNode("//CellDetails/Budget").Text
        UserForm1.txtComments.Text = XDoc.SelectSingleNode("//CellDetails/Comments").Text

        ' Setting the dates
        UserForm1.MonthView1.Value = CDate(XDoc.SelectSingleNode("//CellDetails/StartDate").Text)
        UserForm1.lbStartDate = XDoc.SelectSingleNode("//CellDetails/StartDate").Text
        UserForm1.MonthView2.Value = CDate(XDoc.SelectSingleNode("//CellDetails/EndDate").Text)
        UserForm1.lbEndDate = XDoc.SelectSingleNode("//CellDetails/EndDate").Text
    End If

    UserForm1.Show


    Cancel = True

End If
On Error GoTo 0
```

End Sub